# jQuery Toggling Text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to toggle text when I click to expand/collapse a div. I have written the half of the code that toggles the div and changes to text one-way, but I am trying to figure out how to have it effectively "reset" so a user and toggle back and forth (between "Less Info -" and "More Info +").

Here's the code so far:

```
$("a.more_info").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked").next().slideToggle(1000);
$(this).replaceWith("<a class='more_info' href='#'>Less Info -</a>");
return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Thanks

**EDIT:** The pertinent markup looks like this:

```
<a class="more_info" href="#">More Info +</a>
<div class="project_toggle">
    <h6>Hello</h6>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could instead change the text of the current link instead of replacing the element...

```
$("a.more_info").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass("clicked").next().slideToggle(1000);
    $this.text($this.is(".clicked") ? "Less Info -" : "More Info +");
    return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});
```

Of course you might have to reverse the logic inside the `text()` method depending on what clicked means.

Comment: Or, to prevent text replacement: `<a class="more_info" href="#"><span class="text_more">More Info +</span><span class="text_less">Less Info -</span></a>`, `.text_less, .text_more.clicked { display: none; } .text_less.clicked { display: inline; }`.

Comment: `hasClass` is probably better than using `is`